# Bootstrap 4 navbar toggler not working when browser is minimized and not displaying list

Tags: bootstrap-4

```css
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="js/jquery.js"> </script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css"> 
    
    </style>
    <body>
      
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
              <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Franky</a>
              <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarmenu">
                  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
              </button>
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="#navbarmenu">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">sign in</li>
                      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">register</li>
                      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact Us</li>
                      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">FAQ</li>
                      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Privacy</li>
                    </ul>
              </div>
         
          
        </nav>
      
    </body>
```

i tippled checked the code but i cant figure out why the toggler wont show the list.     when i have the Opera Browser  maximized the  LI wrapped in UL displays Horizontally on the navbar. then when minimize it shows the hamburger icon but no content in it.??

Comment: The id is wrong. It should be: `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarmenu">` not `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="#navbarmenu">`

Comment: thank you so much. it works now.   also i was missing all the </a> tags  :)